# String template inside symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig, twig-extension

I am trying to use string as a template for sending an email. Some what like this.

```
$twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String());
$rendered = $twig->render(
  "Test string template: {{ result }}",
  array("result" => "Success!")
);
```

But this does not allow me to use Symfony extensions. I Googled bit and I found that better way is to use something like

```
{{ include(template_from_string("Hello {{ name }}")) }}
```

with service configuration like this somewhat

```
acme.twig.extension.loader:
class:        Twig_Extension_StringLoader
tags:
     - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

However, I am not use how can I use this extenstion i.e how to pass data (array) in this case and where to to put this piece of code....in another template?

Can someone give me any hint please...

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html - you need to render a twig temlate(in separate file) for example $this->renderView(
                'HelloBundle:Hello:email.txt.twig',
                ['name' => $name]
            ) from controler. It will return you rendered template.

Comment: That won't work for me. In my case content for the template comes from DB not saved in some file like what that example shows.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't allow you to use extensions? All the actual loader (as far as I can see) does it load the contents of the named template into a string and then return that.

Comment: NOT CLEAN SOLUTION. Write what you get from db to file tmp_email.html.twig .That a PHP it' not a probem to use some magic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "renderView" ?

```
$emailBody = $this->renderView('TestBundle:Default:emailTemplate.html.twig', array(
    'result' => 'Success!'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently run into a similar issue (outside symphony), and what worked for me was

```
$twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String(), array('debug'=>true));
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    $twig->addExtension(new \Twig_Extension_Debug());
}
$twig = apply_filters('twig_apply_filters', $twig);
$twig = apply_filters('timber/twig/filters', $twig);
$twig = apply_filters('timber/twig/functions', $twig);
$twig = apply_filters('timber/twig/escapers', $twig);
$twig = apply_filters('timber/loader/twig', $twig);
```

Basically, these are the filters that the timber loader uses when instantiating a new twig instance. This brings in a variety of twig functions, filters, etc...

Once your $twig is properly filled out, you should be able to render your string template adequately.